# PHP help me please for this code i want 10 output results

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have code like that

```
$teachersql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `teacher` WHERE status = '2' ORDER BY name") or die(mysql_error());
while($teachers = mysql_fetch_array($teachersql)) 
{ 
  echo "results"; 
}
```

But I have 100 results. I want only first 10 result in output. How? Please anybody help me now.

Comment: use "limit" in your query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$teachersql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher 
                           WHERE status = '2' 
                           ORDER BY name 
                           LIMIT 10")
```

**The mandatory warning:**

`mysql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need 10 result in result set then you can make your code as below using **limit**.

```
$teachersql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `teacher` WHERE status = '2' ORDER BY name limit 10") or die(mysql_error());
```

or

if you want to fetch all rows and display only 10 result using while loop then you can use counter as below.

```
$cnt=0;
while($teachers = mysql_fetch_array($teachersql)) 
{ 
   $cnt++;
  echo "results";
   if($cnt==10)
      break; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE status = '2' ORDER BY name limit 10
```

Comment: Why post the same answer multiple minutes later?